# startActivity(intent) not working inside Firebase onDataChange()

Tags: android, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, android-intent

I'm changing activity inside the firebase `onDataChange()` method.

It executes till this line `intent3.putExtra("heading", newHeading)` but it doesn't opens `TargetActivity` rather it opens some other default activity.

Kindly help, thank you in advance.

```
DatabaseReference reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
reference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        String newHeading = "";
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(subIndex)) {
                newHeading = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            }
        }
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TargetActivity.class);
        intent3.putExtra("heading", newHeading);
        startActivity(intent3);
    }

});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The fact it's in `onDataChange()` shouldn't make a difference at all. Have you tried trying to just start `TargetActivity` elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It's working outside onDataChange(). When it takes time to fetch data then it doesn't work.
Btw I fetched data in the onCreate() method and I'm using intent in another onClick event method. So, now it's working fine.

Comment: I cannot see any reason why your `TargetActivity` could not be started. Are you starting another activity from another place in your code?

Comment: Yes, I got the issue. Actually, I was calling another activity in the same Java file